# Android navigation drawer glitch / stuck every time

Tags: android, android-layout

In android navigation drawer stuck when different item is selected ,I have also implemented android:clickable="true" but it doesn't make any effect

```
 I have attached a sample screenshot explaining how it stuck.


     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>


   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_menu_start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />
```

Comment: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3332036/5587539/8a15101c-9117-11e4-804b-63c556eec891.png

Answer (score 0):

Which operation are you performing when you click an item? The operation is surely blocking the UI. Can you move the operation to another thread or just use async task for the operation. Something is blocking the UI